# form action in codeigniter

Tags: forms, codeigniter

I have a form in which the action is `SiteController/actionLogin`. If the user submits and doesn't get logged in, the URL changes to `http://localhost/MySite/SiteController/actionLogin`
and another attempt will be like this

```
http://localhost/MySite/SiteController/SiteController/actionLogin
```

How can this be fixed?

I am using CodeIgniter PHP framework.

Answer (score 1):

Put a `/` in front of the form action to tell the browser that it's an absolute URL:

```
action="/SiteController/actionLogin"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `site_url('SiteController/actionLogin')` to echo your url. [Here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) is the documentation.